# How would one say "Please let me do X thing"

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice

Was wondering how one would say "Please let me do X thing" e.g. "Please let me love/win/see"

Would you use some sort of impersonal construction, or would one use "permitto"?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you mean like a general wish ("Please let me do well on that test tomorrow!"), or actually asking someone for permission to do something?

Comment: the latter, I think, although now I'm curious as to what the first would be as well!

Answer (score 9):

There would of course be many possibilities, but I believe the verb [*sinere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsino) comes closest to “let.” It can be used in various ways – with an AcI, with *ut* – but the most compact form would be a bare subjunctive.

“Let me love” then would be: **Sine amem** – and while I did not find that specific expression in the literature, I did find in Plautus' [*Casina*](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/plautus/cas.shtml) (2,2; [English here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0097%3Aact%3D2%3Ascene%3D2)):

> Sine amet, sine quod lubet id faciat
> *Let him love, let him do what he wants*

Answer (score 2):

As Sebastian points out, there are many ways to say this. His example of *sine* with the subjunctive is probably one of the more natural ways to do it, *Sine, quaeso, ut X faciam*.

You can, however, use *permitte*: *Permitte, quaeso, me X facere*. *Permittere* is a rather more concrete verb than *sinere*, it seems to me. It means to let someone pass (a gate, a wall, a line of armed guards) to do something. Of course, this concrete meaning can be used metaphorically to mean basically the same thing as *sinere*.

If you have your heart set on an impersonal construction, you could say, *Mihi liceat, quaeso, X facere*. "Let it be allowed to me to do X."